# hyperlinks in html won't work with embedded code

Tags: html, sharepoint, hyperlink, embed, embedding

I am trying to embed html code into a content box/embed code box on sharepoint.

The code works fine in dreamweaver where i can preview it, but once i paste the code into the embed box and click save, all my content shows up but any link that I've created is not "clickable."

Here is my code:

```html
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="overlay"> 
      <h1>​WHS changing name to 1100 Trancas​ 
         <span class="button">
            <a href="/olenews/default.aspx"></a>Read More</span> </h1>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the "Read More" text clickable, you have to move it like so:

```html
   <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="overlay"> 
      <h1>​WHS changing name to 1100 Trancas​ 
         <span class="button">
            <a href="/olenews/default.aspx">Read More</a></span> </h1>
   </div>
```

As you can see the "Read More" text is blue.
While the "Read More" in your code is still black

What I did was moved the "Read More" text inbetween the opener a and the closer a so that the href stated will apply to the text.

Also, may I ask what the link is to the site you are developing?

EDIT: rewrote entire answer

Comment: Hi there sorry i put too much code. The part i am trying to make "clickable" is the "Read More" part of the code. Which i made through css, so it's not necessarily an image file. I edited the code the above to reflect what i mean.

Comment: @Rich Homie Nanz Re-wrote my answer!

Comment: you're a genius! that totally worked. I can't express how thankful i am!